# How to compare float variables in awk?

Tags: command-line, scripts, awk

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{c[$29]=$29;next} NF{print $29 ((c[$29]==$29)?" ":",mismatch")}' $file1 $file2
```

The value of 29th field, i.e., $29 in file1 was 832.9 and that of file2 was 832.9000. If I compare them they are not equal. I think it is taking as a string rather than a number.

How should I proceed?

Comment: Weird. To make, this works as they are compared properly: `echo "832.9000 832.9" | awk '$1==$2'`.

Comment: Adding to A.B.'s answer, this old post of mine might be helpful; you should be careful when comparing floating points numbers: http://askubuntu.com/a/634409/380067

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`awk` compares floating point numbers:**

I just wrote a new script:

```
paste \
    <(awk -F, '{print $29}' file1 ) \
    <(awk -F, '{print $29}' file2 ) \
    | awk '{print $1; print $2; print ($1==$2)?"match" :"mismatch"}'
```

If you do not like breaks, then use `printf` instead of `print.`

---

*Example*

Input files

`cat file1`

```
12,2,12,12,12,12,3,2,53,6,5474,346,567,6578,89,7689,7,987,69869,1,4,5,4,3,4,2,6,21,832.9,9,2
12,2,12,12,12,12,3,2,53,6,5474,346,567,6578,89,7689,7,987,69869,1,4,5,4,3,4,2,6,21,12.329,9,2
```

`cat file2`

```
12,2,12,12,12,12,3,2,53,6,5474,346,567,6578,89,7689,7,987,69869,1,4,5,4,3,4,2,6,21,832.9000,9,2
12,2,12,12,12,12,3,2,53,6,5474,346,567,6578,89,7689,7,987,69869,1,4,5,4,3,4,2,6,21,832.9000,9,2
```

Output

```
% paste <(awk -F, '{print $29}' file1 ) <(awk -F, '{print $29}' file2 ) | awk '{print $1; print $2; print ($1==$2)?"match" :"mismatch"}'

832.9
832.9000
match
12.329
832.9000
mismatch
```

Comment: So whatever we store in an array is treated as string, am I correct @A.B.