# Specific edits to a text file (awk?)

Tags: bash, awk, text-processing

I have a file that looks like

```
TITLE
1.000000000000000
10.0000000000000000    0.0000000000000000    0.0000000000000000 
0.0000000000000000   10.0000000000000000    0.0000000000000000
0.0000000000000000    0.0000000000000000   10.0000000000000000
U   U
X   X
C
0.2000000000000028  0.2000000000000028  0.2000000000000028
0.2967599999999990  0.0641000000000034  0.1551499999999990
0.1033699999999982  0.3361099999999979  0.244990000000001
```

and I need to have a script that will modify the bottom number block (below `C` to 30 less than their original values. Is there any such way to do so?

So far, the best I've got is

```
$ awk '{if(NR>1){for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){$(i)=$(i)-10;}}print;}' data.txt | column -t
```

but, that's from the internet and I'm not sure how to manipulate it myself to the desired effect. This however will not print/overwrite what's currently in `data.txt`, which is what I'm going for.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do the numbers have to be stored in the file (again) or to be extracted from- ?

Comment: Ah never mind, I see :)

Comment: @jcklasseter how the output numbers are supposed to look like ?

Comment: @Serg Good point, litarally -30 is probably not what OP means :), so 
`0.0000000000000030`?

Comment: @jcklasseter We need more information...

Comment: @JacobVlijm Sorry. If I had 30, I want it to then be 0. If I have 22.5, I want it to be changed to -7.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my awk version :

`awk '/^C/,0 {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { if ( $i != "C" )  printf "%.16f ",$i-30.0000};print"\n" }' data.txt`

Here we get all the stuff from C character till the end of file, subtract 30 in each column, add newline, and repeat the process.The if statement added to avoid subtracting 30 from C, obviously.

The output is this :

```
    46)serg@ubuntu[/home/xieerqi]
    >_ awk '/^C/,0 {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { if ( $i != "C" )  printf "%.16f ",$i-30.0000};print"\n" }' data.txt                             

-29.7999999999999972 -29.7999999999999972 -29.7999999999999972 

-29.7032400000000010 -29.9358999999999966 -29.8448500000000010 

-29.8966300000000018 -29.6638900000000021 -29.7550099999999986
```

This can be substituted in the original file; Alternativelly we could always try to print stuff before C with a BEGIN { } statement

Comment: Each row has all the same values...

Comment: Ah I see it m ive put. $1 where $ I should be

Comment: @yaegashi fixed, had a small typo in the code

Answer (score 3):

Given `data.awk` below:

```
{
        if (matched) {
                for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
                        $(i) = 30.0 - $(i)
                }
        }
        print
}
/^C/ { matched = 1 }
BEGIN { CONVFMT = "%.20f" }
```

You get:

```
$ awk -f data.awk data.txt
TITLE
1.000000000000000
10.0000000000000000    0.0000000000000000    0.0000000000000000 
0.0000000000000000   10.0000000000000000    0.0000000000000000
0.0000000000000000    0.0000000000000000   10.0000000000000000
U   U
X   X
C
29.79999999999999715783 29.79999999999999715783 29.79999999999999715783
29.70324000000000097543 29.93589999999999662350 29.84485000000000098908
29.89663000000000181444 29.66389000000000208956 29.75500999999999862666
```

It obviously has precision problem for your input.  So you might want to call `bc` command for actual calculations (it supports arbitrary precision):

```
{
        if (matched) {
                for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
                        cmd = "echo 30.0 - " $(i) " | bc"
                        cmd | getline $(i)
                        close(cmd)
                }
        }
        print
}
/^C/ { matched = 1 }
```

Result:

```
TITLE
1.000000000000000
10.0000000000000000    0.0000000000000000    0.0000000000000000 
0.0000000000000000   10.0000000000000000    0.0000000000000000
0.0000000000000000    0.0000000000000000   10.0000000000000000
U   U
X   X
C
29.7999999999999972 29.7999999999999972 29.7999999999999972
29.7032400000000010 29.9358999999999966 29.8448500000000010
29.8966300000000018 29.6638900000000021 29.755009999999999
```

To overwrite `data.txt` with the result, you normally need to write it to another file, then rename it to the original file.

```
$ awk -f data.awk data.txt > data.txt.out
$ mv data.txt.out data.txt
```

Or use `sponge` in [moreutils](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/).

```
$ sudo apt-get install moreutils
$ awk -f data.awk data.txt | sponge data.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `python`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import decimal
with open('/path/to/data.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.rstrip() == 'C':
            print line.rstrip()
            break
        else:
            print line.rstrip()
    for line in f:
        print '\t'.join(['{0:.16f}'.format(decimal.Decimal(30 - float(part))) for part in line.rstrip().split()])
```

**Output :**

```
TITLE
1.000000000000000
10.0000000000000000    0.0000000000000000    0.0000000000000000
0.0000000000000000   10.0000000000000000    0.0000000000000000
0.0000000000000000    0.0000000000000000   10.0000000000000000
U   U
X   X
C
29.7999999999999972 29.7999999999999972 29.7999999999999972
29.7032400000000010 29.9358999999999966 29.8448500000000010
29.8966300000000018 29.6638900000000021 29.7550099999999986
```

- Every time `python` reads a line of the file the pointer is increased by one to point to the next line, we are utilizing this to read and print upto the line that contains only `C`.
- For the lines after `C` we have splitted the line into parts by `line.rstrip().split()` and then subtracted each part from `30` to get the desired result.
- To get precision on the resultant floating point number we have used the `decimal` module.

Comment: Last one should be `29.7550099999999990`?

Comment: @yaegashi I have taken precision upto 16 digits as OP did too and it seems right to me..

Comment: The last input `0.244990000000001` is itself out of capability of `float`.  Use `decimal.Decimal(part)` instead of `float(part)`.  `decimal` makes sense when used in the calculation.

Answer (score 1):

I can't provide a good solution to the problem, but I'll try to describe in depth what the problem is and I'll provide a partial solution.

**The problem**:

Floating point numbers on machines suffer from limited precision: in short, only a limited subset of floating point numbers [per each order of magnitude] is representable.

Floating point numbers on machines are represented closely following the normalized notation `± significand * base ^ exponent` (where `base` = base of representation, `significand` = any real number > 0 and <= the base of representation and where `exponent` = order of magnitude): for example, on a 32-bit machine following the `IEEE 754` standard, single-precision floating point numbers are represented using the first bit to represent the sign, the following 8 bits to represent the order of magnitude and the last 23 bits to represent the significand, while double-precision floating point numbers are represented using the first bit to represent the sign, the following 11 bits to represent the order of magnitude and the last 52 bits to represent the significand (the base, being always 2, is not represented). For this, a number's significand has to be represented always using 23 bits (using single-precision) or using 52 bits (using double-precision).

A property of this way of representing floating point numbers on a fixed number of bits is that being the number of representable significands per order of magnitude always the same, the average "distance" between representable floating point numbers with the same order of magnitude increases as the order of magnitude of the two increases.

For the above, the first problem is that if a floating point number's normalized notation's significand is not in the limited set of representable significands, it's rounded to the closest (higher or lower) significand representable.

Speaking of numbers represented with the same order of magnitude, a second problem is that even when a floating point number is representable precisely, adding / substracting another [precisely representable] floating point number to it might result in a not precisely representable floating point number, whose significand will be rounded to the closest (higher or lower) significand representable.

Finally, speaking of numbers represented with a different order of magnitude, the third problem (mostly due to the CPU architecture) is that in order to be able to perform additions / substractions between floating point numbers represented with a different order of magnitude, the numbers need to be first represented using the same order of magnitude; this implies that the smallest one's order of magnitude needs to be increased, and that (in order to balance this) its significand needs to be shifted to the right, with the consequent loss of the number of bits exceeding the 23 / 52 available; if this is not enough, floating point numbers with a significant difference in their order of magnitude might result, once added / substracted, exactly in the number with the highest absolute value, this for the already stated problem (not enough difference to step the non representable significand up / down to a different higher / lower representable significand) and increasingly worse as the order of magnitude of two numbers diverges further.

The implications of all of this are: you'll never be sure to get an accurate result using floating point math, however this can be mitigated by using an higher-precision representation.

**The partial solution**:

For the above, the results of these `awk` one-liners are not precise; this could have been mitigated by the usage of double-precision in their `printf` commands, but this is not supported.

---

This will decrease by `30` the value of the first 3 space-separated numbers in each line after the first line matching `C`, keeping the numbers' format. Since the `awk` version included in Ubuntu does not support in-place edits, you'll have to either use `awk` and redirect its `stdout` to a file using `bash`'s `>` operator or use `gawk` (GNU `awk`) >= `4.10.0`;

Using `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==1, $0=="C"; $0=="C", 0 {if ($0!="C") printf "%.16f  %.16f  %.16f\n", $1-30, $2-30, $3-30}' data.txt > data_processed.txt
```

Using `gawk` (GNU `awk`) >= `4.10.0`

```
gawk -i inplace 'NR==1, $0=="C"; $0=="C", 0 {if ($0!="C") printf "%.16f  %.16f  %.16f\n", $1-30, $2-30, $3-30}' data.txt
```

- `NR==1, $0=="C";`: selects and prints all the records between the first and the first matching `C` inclusive;
- `$0=="C", 0 {if ($0!="C") printf "%.16f  %.16f  %.16f\n", $1-30, $2-30, $3-30}`: selects all the records between the first matching `C` and the last inclusive and prints the 1st, 2nd and 3rd field of each selected record not matching `C` double-space separated and decreased by `30` keeping the original number's format;

Sample output:

```
~/tmp$ cat data.txt
TITLE
1.000000000000000
10.0000000000000000    0.0000000000000000    0.0000000000000000 
0.0000000000000000   10.0000000000000000    0.0000000000000000
0.0000000000000000    0.0000000000000000   10.0000000000000000
U   U
X   X
C
0.2000000000000028  0.2000000000000028  0.2000000000000028
0.2967599999999990  0.0641000000000034  0.1551499999999990
0.1033699999999982  0.3361099999999979  0.244990000000001
~/tmp$ awk 'NR==1, $0=="C"; $0=="C", 0 {if ($0!="C") printf "%.16f  %.16f  %.16f\n", $1-30, $2-30, $3-30}' data.txt
TITLE
1.000000000000000
10.0000000000000000    0.0000000000000000    0.0000000000000000 
0.0000000000000000   10.0000000000000000    0.0000000000000000
0.0000000000000000    0.0000000000000000   10.0000000000000000
U   U
X   X
C
-29.7999999999999972  -29.7999999999999972  -29.7999999999999972
-29.7032400000000010  -29.9358999999999966  -29.8448500000000010
-29.8966300000000018  -29.6638900000000021  -29.7550099999999986
```